# Ubuntu doesn't detect my headsets

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I can't manage to make Ubuntu detect my headsets. When they are not plugged, speakers work normally, however when I plug them, sound disappears, meaning it detects that my headphones are plugged but can't cast any sound in it. In the sound setup, the "Speakers" options are replaced by "Line output" options that don't seem to work.

Here are some tests outputs :

```
$ amixer -c 0
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  $ amixer -c 0
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono: Playback 60 [69%] [-20.25dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-65.25dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-65.25dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Bass Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-65.25dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-65.25dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Line Out',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958 Default PCM',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 63
  Front Left: Capture 35 [56%] [9.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 35 [56%] [9.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Enabled'
Simple mixer control 'Loopback Mixing',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Enabled'
```

Second card that doesn't seel to be of any use

```
$ amixer -c 1
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
```

And a driver recap :

```
$ aplay -lL
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC668 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC668 Analog
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC668 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC668 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC668 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC668 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC668 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC668 Analog
     7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC668 Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC668 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC668 Digital
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC668 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC668 Digital
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC668 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC668 Digital
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC668 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC668 Digital
    Hardware device with all software conversions
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
   Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Hardware device with all software conversions
**** Liste des Périphériques Matériels PLAYBACK ****
carte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 0: ALC668 Analog [ALC668 Analog]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 1: ALC668 Digital [ALC668 Digital]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], périphérique 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], périphérique 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
```

Can't find any subject that solves my problem so I end up asking. 
Thank you in advance.

EDIT : [Here is a screenshot of my volume controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caRnk.png)

Comment: Up to now all my problems regarding audio became trivial after installing `pavucontrol`. Have a look at what it offers.

Comment: On `pavucontrol`, once i launch a youtube vid or anything it tells me there is sound playing in the line output, but i can't hear anything. The other controller I can access is the HDMI one, but i am plugged in jack.

Answer (score 0):

Please open Sound Setting (Volume Control) -> Output Devices. You can see I have Headphones plugged in. Make sure the slider is not set to Silence.

[image]

Comment: My headphones are not detected as said, they don't appear here, and the only option I get is not silenced. I'm gonna edit a screenshot in my question so you can see.

Comment: For a pure technical perspective, it is not the headphones that are detected but the insertion of the jack. That seems to be confirmed by your remark "plug the headset in, the sound disappears".  I would expect your "Sortie ligne/Line Out" to change to "Casque/Headphones". That is the behavior in my system at least. I have 2 green connectors, read and front. Speakers are in the rear, Line Out is showing. Plug in the headphone in the front, Line Out changes to Headphones (as per my screenshot). I cannot think of another item in Sound Settings that will toggle when headphones are plugged in.

Comment: I will have a look at my notes about the `pacmd` tool to see if routing of input sinks (input sources) to output sinks (output devices) could have something to do with it.  Just curious about your headset... it does work on for example your phone ???  ;-)  just asking...

Comment: That is chat i understood, the jack is detected but the headphones are not. My headset works perfectly on windows or on my phone, so I expect it to be a driver problem. I can't find drivers on the net to manually install though. My headset is a Gamecom 380 from plantronics, not sure if it can help.

Comment: Lets find out what PulseAudio can tell us. Please remove the headset jack and issue the command: `pacmd list-sinks `.  I would like to know: how many sinks are available (1st output line, I expect 2 sinks). Which index has an * preceding (I expect:  * index: 2). At the end of index 2 you find: ports: (I expect 3, Line Out, Speakers, Headphones) and active port: (I expect analog-output=speaker). Now plugin the headset and give the command again. Check active port. I expect analog-output-headphones.

Comment: If not '* index: 2', please look at ports: and active port: of the index that does have the *.

Comment: Pardon.. I meant *index: 1  is probably the active sink...

Comment: I have 2 sinks, index 0 and 4. The index 4 has a * preceding. I have 2 ports : analog-output-lineout and analog-output-speakers. The speakers are indee active. When i plug the kac in, the linout becomes active. The headphones port is non-existent :/

Comment: Well after rebooting the second index is now 1, guess it is not important

Comment: Ok, I will try to duplicate your situation in my system. In the meantime, and this may sound strange... but try and exchange the jacks. Plug the speakers jack in the connector where you plugged the 'kac' and the kac in and out the connector where the speakers were. What happens then?

Comment: I'm on a laptop so my speakers are integrated in the computer. The only other jack that is plugged in is the mic (which i'm not sure is working but it is not much of a problem for now)

Comment: Ahhhh... now we/I have something in common. I tried my own laptop and it turns outI have exactly the same problem. Playing sound over internal speakers, plug in earphones and nothing changes. OK... I will dive into this and get back to you when I find a solution.

Comment: Bad news, I'm afraid. I cannot get my headphones to work on my Lenovo T420. Neither in Windows 7x64 nor in Xubuntu 16.04. A search on the internet revealed I am not the only T420 owner with this problem. I tried the latest Conexant driver but nothing. Speakers just fine, headset not. So I now am out of ideas and have no solution for you. If the hardware is not recognized then the software will not aid us to a solution.

Comment: It was a pleasure and an eye-opener for me. I now know that my laptop is not 100% ;-))